# Magento layout XML not instantiating blocks

Tags: magento

I've mucked around a bit with this and I've tried all kinds of different values from various sites and a couple e-books on the subject. The total lack of any semblance of consistency has made this more difficult than I feel it should be.

Basically I cannot get it to use `content.phtml` to override the `content` section in the main template. I have done it by forcing it through the controller like so:

```
$content = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(...);
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($content);
```

But I feel this makes my module inflexible, and makes parts of the configuration redundant and misleading.

I am using a block called `Company_AdvSearch_Block_Results` which extends `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.

**File: config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_AdvSearch>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_AdvSearch>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <advsearch>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_AdvSearch</module>
                    <frontName>advsearch</frontName>
                </args>
            </advsearch>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <advsearch module="Company_AdvSearch">
                    <file>advsearch.xml</file>
                </advsearch>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <advsearch>
                <class>Company_AdvSearch_Block</class>
            </advsearch>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**File: advsearch.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <advsearch_index_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle">
                <title>Advanced Search</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="advsearch/results" name="advsearch" template="advsearch/content.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </advsearch_index_index>
</layout>
```

So:

1. How would I get it to actually update the `content` section of the layout?
2. How would I update other parts (i.e. `left`) using my module so they can access the same data?

**Update**

I've run into yet another issue. After inserting this block, the referenced components successfully disappeared.

```
<reference name="left">
    <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
    <remove name="left.reports.product.viewed"/>
    <remove name="catalog.product.related"/>
</reference>
```

Now, after commenting this block and even deleting the file from the server, I can't get those parts to come back on this page. It seems to be disregarding the XML file entirely (both normal caching and compiler caching are disabled).

Comment: did you try simply calling this 2 lines in your action      `$this->loadLayout();$this->renderLayout();`

Comment: I suppose I should have specified that. Yes, they're in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue myself. A checklist:

1. Make sure you can instantiate your block from the controller. If it can't you have an issue with `config.xml`.
2. Make sure the correct handle (the wrapping element in the layout XML document) is being used (mine wasn't) and that other handles aren't running to overwrite any of its changes. Add this line to your controller to get the list of handles:

   `var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate()->getHandles());`
3. In my case, someone else on the team had removed components from the base template without letting me know. Make sure the removed components actually exist in the template first.
4. Make sure your module is actually enabled from the control panel in `System > Configuration > Advanced`.

Current working configurations:

**File: config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_AdvSearch>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page/>
                <Mage_Catalog/>
            </depends>
        </Company_AdvSearch>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <company_advsearch>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_AdvSearch</module>
                    <frontName>advsearch</frontName>
                </args>
            </company_advsearch>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <company_advsearch module="Company_AdvSearch">
                    <file>advsearch.xml</file>
                </company_advsearch>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <company_advsearch>
                <class>Company_AdvSearch_Block</class>
            </company_advsearch>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <company_advsearch>
                <class>Company_AdvSearch_Helper</class>
            </company_advsearch>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**File: advsearch.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <company_advsearch_index_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle">
                <title>Advanced Search</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="company_advsearch/results" name="search_criteria" as="left" template="advsearch/left.phtml" before="-"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="company_advsearch/results" name="search_results" as="content" template="advsearch/content.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </company_advsearch_index_index>
</layout>
```